# Express js sending app variable to routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to send some data from the app (var app = express();) variable to some code Socket.IO related and sending a value to some middleware kind of the same way:

```
function routes(app) {
    app.post('/evento', function (req, res) {
        evento.novoEvento(req, res, app);//passing app to the method evento.novoEvento
    });
    app.put('/evento', function (req, res) {
            restringeAcao(req, res, 'Evento');//passing the string 'Evento' to the method evento.alteraEvento
        }, evento.alteraEvento);
    });

}
```

It does work but I never seen any example like this. My question is: is there a reason no one uses it like this? If so what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express already has a property on both `req.app` and `res.app` you can use to access the application object the contains the request and response. Thus any route handler function or middleware has easy access to the `app` instance.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using the res.app just fine.

Comment: @desoares Please accept this answer then so others can see the question has been answered. Thanks.